# How To Approach My Employer about Renewing my Contract?

Tags: contract-extension

I have an employment contract that is ending on 12/31/18.  The last time I talked with my boss was 5 weeks ago and he just answered vaguely that we don’t know if any of us are going to have a job.  We are an at will state.  He said that none of our jobs are secure.  He also said not to worry, that he talked with corporate and they seemed happy with me and so is he.  There is nothing negative.

It is 3 months away before I have to get employed again.  How should I handle it with HR?  I don’t want to get into trouble with my boss because I didn’t talk to him directly again but I really need to know if I should start looking for another job.

Answer (score 5):

You should start looking for a new job, and skip HR (Their job to protect the company from lawsuits).

There could be many reasons why they are not starting new contract negotiations, which are probably not in your favor. If you just wait and see, you will likely be in a poor spot to negotiate, or worst case be out of a job.

If you have a job offer, then you are in a better position to negotiate, and even in a better position to start negotiations with the company. More importantly though is going to be your piece of mind that you will have work next year.

Comment: Hi J,  thank you.  I needed to hear that.  I have started the process and not looking back.  It is too bad.  I really love my position and love working for my boss.

Answer (score 2):

Look for work now, but also think about what you'll do if your current employer still wants you.

I had a 3 month contract which was never extended but I was there for 13 years.  My wife is told she has a job only a week or two before the semester starts.  This is pretty common for contractors or "temporary" workers.  It's shifting all the uncertainty onto you in case the budget (or whatever) doesn't work.

You might also talk to your boss and ask him when you'll know because you need to start looking for work if the answer is no... but he might not know himself if he has budget for you.  Something to point out is it's strongly in his best interests to keep you not looking for work in case they do need/want you and you find something better.

Answer (score 0):

> he just answered vaguely that we don’t know if any of us are going to have a job. We are an at will state. He said that none of our jobs are secure.

That response is flippant and rude. His personal political commentary is not needed.  There are *MILLIONS* of us working in "at will" states, and we know the budgets for the next 6, 12, and 24 months.  We know they can change, but we know what they are, now.

Your "boss" seems anything but.  I believe you need to get him to grow up and/or get out of the way.

"Who should we ask about the intention of renewing my contract.  I really like working here, and enjoy the job, but I need to have a realistic answer of what the intention is about my contract for next year."

Also - your contract ending at the end of the calendar year is a bit of an issue.  Most people don't bring on contractors in the last quarter of the year.  I'd start looking, now, and I'd review your contract for terms on early termination.  Your boss's childish posturing about "at-will states" tells me it's not a good place to be.